# List comprehension for creating distance list

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have to create a list where each element is a list of form:
[d,i,j]

where i, j are indexes of two points, d is euclidian distance between them. Since distance between (i,j) is the same as distance between (j,i), I do this

```
dist=[]   
for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            dist.append([math.hypot(x[i]-x[j],y[i]-y[j]),i,j])
```

This gives me what I want:

[[0.0, 0, 0], [0.0, 1, 1], [1.0, 0, 2], [1.0, 0, 3], [1.0, 1, 2], [1.0, 2, 0], [1.0, 2, 1], [1.0, 3, 0], [1.4142135623730951, 0, 1], [1.4142135623730951, 1, 0]]

I tried using list comprehension but made a list of list of lists:

```
dist = [[[math.hypot(x[i]-x[j],y[i]-y[j]),i,j] for j in range(i,n)] for i in range(n)]
```

But it created something else entirely:
[[[0.0, 0, 0], [1.0, 0, 1], [1.0, 0, 2], [1.4142135623730951, 0, 3]], [[0.0, 1, 1], [1.4142135623730951, 1, 2], [1.0, 1, 3]], [[0.0, 2, 2], [1.0, 2, 3]], [[0.0, 3, 3]]]

Is there some compact list comprehension method achieve the result from the explicit for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure is the equivalent of:

```
dist = [[math.hypot(x[i] - x[j], y[i] - y[j]), i, j] for i in range(n) for j in range(i, n)]
```